# Find the chromatic polynomial to a graph (am i doing it wrong?)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I tried to find the chromatic polynomial for this graph:

[image]

But the right answer should be:
$$
P(G,\lambda) = \lambda(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 2)^5(\lambda^2 -3\lambda+3)
$$

My answer is:
$$
P(G,\lambda) = \lambda(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda-2)^6 = 
$$
$$
P(G,\lambda) =\lambda(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 2)^5(\lambda^2 -3\lambda+2)
$$

So they are very similar, i have checked the nodes and tried different approaches but i always end up with the same result... 
My question is, how would the image that i attached look if it was drawn using the right answer? Because the expression in the last parenthesis does not make any sense to me to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the numerous edits guys. Now, if some one would look at the actual question that would be great ;D

Comment: The main trick to finding the chromatic polynomial by marking nodes one at a time, is to find suitable "chains" of nodes to follow, and to do one chain at a time. I see that you have started at the node marked $\lambda$, and then gone both up into the square and southwest one node "at the same time". Then those two "chains" seem to collide in the northwest of the top square. That is where inconsistencies in the number of available colors for the nodes occur, and ultimately where you went wrong. Ask yourself: "Do the NE and SW nodes of the square have to have different colors?"

Comment: In fact, I think the top square alone destroys any attempts to find the chromatic polynomial with the "marking nodes" method…Perhaps you should switch to using the deletion / contraction method? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Deletion.E2.80.93contraction

Comment: @A.Sh the wiki article does not give any example using the algorithm, so i dont really know how to start. But if i understand correctly i can somehow delete the top square using this method?

Comment: Ah, yes the wiki page really should have a visual example. The method is as follows: 1) Pick an edge,  2) Delete that edge. The resulting graph is called $G-uv$ in the wiki. 3) Compute the chromatic polynomial of $G-uv$, you might have to restart this method on that graph to do this. 4) In the original graph, "contract" the selected edge (visually, just lay the endpoints of the edge on top of each other, and keep all the other edges of the two endpoints with that node. If you contract the top edge of the square for example, you end up with a triangle instead)  5) Compute the chromatic...

Comment: ...polynomial of the contracted graph (the contracted graph is denoted $G/uv$ in the wiki), you might have to restart this method on that graph as well,  6) Subtract the result from step 5 from the result of step 3. This is the final answer. Try looking at slide number 15 here for a visual example: http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Studies/T-79.5203/2008SPR/slides-a5.pdf I recommend you to start with one of the edges of the square to get rid of it as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comments with an actual solution, here is how I would solve your problem, drawn in Inkscape (you're welcome):

[image]
[image]

Comment: wow thanks for taking the time to do this :D

Comment: So basicly, if the two chains "collide" i have to use this method instead?

Comment: @user6395724 Yes, if the "mark the nodes" method you wanted to use doesn't work, you _can_ use this method instead. This method always works, but if you can mark the nodes properly, then that is usually faster to do. What I meant by "colliding chains" is that in your first attempt, you seem to approach the NW corner of the square from two directions, and conclude that the NW corner has $\lambda - 2$ choices of color. But you can probably realize that the NE and the SW corners of the square aren't forced to have different colors, which messes everything up.

Comment: Ah okay i think i see how to approach these problems now; first try marking nodes, if this method fails i.e if the colliding chains result in a coloring in the colliding area that should be "better" try to "fix" this area using deletion/contraction.

Comment: @user6395724 Sounds about right.